# Python has crashed after installing keras and tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm studying on ML. I tried to install keras and tensorflow but tensorflow hasn't installed very well . After the installation my project keeps giving me errors .
When i fix an error it gives an another error. This is an example:

> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/YUNUS EMRE/Desktop/MLTEZ.py', wdir='C:/Users/YUNUS EMRE/Desktop')
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 827, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 110, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/YUNUS EMRE/Desktop/MLTEZ.py", line 9, in 
>       import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py",
>   line 34, in 
>       fig, ax = plt.subplots()
>
> AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'subplots'

Comment: I believe `TensorFlow` itself installs `matplotlib` modules, but since you had trouble installing `TensorFlow`, `matplotlib` might have been incorrectly installed. You might wanna install it explicitly.

Comment: Also if you're beginning your ML/DL journey I would suggest you use an online medium of executing your source such as Google Colab instead of using a virtual environment like Anaconda. It helps you to focus on concepts and not configurations.

Comment: You might also wanna, share your code in order to get a better answer.

Comment: you are actually right.I've been trying to fix and configurate tons of things . I'm sick of it :D. But i think i fixed it by reinstalling it . Thx a lot